# No internet with wireless after update to 12.04

Tags: networking

I have upgraded to 12.04 LTS. I read somewhere that it could be the network manager, and that I need to downgrade.. But I am really confused as to how to do this with no internet access while using Ubuntu. I am currently using windows to access the net.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

well I think your wireless drivers may not have installed when you upgraded.

I recommend you find an Ethernet port plug your laptop in and run

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

this should search and install any updates and might grab your wireless drivers.

if not go to your vendors website and try to find the drivers or google the card model and look for drivers. you may have to compile from source and it varies from vendor to vendor so I can't help you there.